# How to run many of same function

Tags: javascript, variables, google-chrome-extension

So What I am trying to do is make it so it runs the first set of code, and then the second, I have tried doing "poodle", "Labrador" but it doesn't work, It opens all of the possible breeds and matches them, how do I get it to match more than one breed ?

```
    (function() {

    var x = document.getElementById("breed_selector).options;
   for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        if(x[i].text=="Labrador"){
            x[i].selected=true;
document.getElementsByClassName("shop")[0].click();
            break;
   }
}

        var x = document.getElementById("breed_selector").options;
   for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        if(x[i].text=="poodle"){
            x[i].selected=true;
document.getElementsByClassName("shop")[0].click();



})();
```

At the moment, it just doesn't do anything,

I have tried

```
var  = document.getElementById("breed_selector").options;
   for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        if(x[i].text=="poodle", "Labrador", "pug"){
            x[i].selected=true;
document.getElementsByClassName("shop")[0].click();
            break;
```

But the above doesn't work either, any input would be great, Thanks :)

UPDATED CODE which still doesn't work

```
(function() {

    var x = document.getElementById("breed_selector").options;
   for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        var text = x[i].text;
        if(x[i].text === "Labrador" && text === "Pug"){
            x[i].selected=true;
document.getElementsByClassName("shop")[0].click();
            break;
   }
}


})();
```

Comment: What is the expected output ? The question is not clear also there is a type here `var x = document.getElementById("breed_selector).options;` Missing closing quotes

Answer (score 0):

Your code have many syntax errors, it's better to clean your code first then come and ask for help.

You not defined your x variable in your second block of code, also your for loop start from 0 but your end condition is the length of the object. If you start from 0 you need to loop up to `x.length - 1`

Comment: Thanks, I have updated it within myself, and there also has been a reply

Answer (score 0):

The operator you need is `||`, which signifies "OR" in a series of expressions.

In the context of your problem, you would make the following change:

```
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){

    var text = x[i].text;

    if(text === "poodle" || text === "Labrador" || text === "pug") {

        x[i].selected=true;
        document.getElementsByClassName("shop")[0].click();
        break;
    }
}
```

In plain words, the `if` statement asks "is `text` equal to a `poodle` OR equal to a `Labrador` OR equal to a `pug`?"

Comment: Perfect, Thanks for the speedy response, except I guess I'm looking for the AND equivalent because I want it to select all three, not just pick one :)

Thank you

I added the new code, but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: If you could explain why it doesn't find one breed, click find the next and then click again that would be of great use :)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the `if` statement to evaluate to `true` when text is equal to a `poodle`, `Labrador`, or `pug`, right? If that's the case, you would use the code in my answer, which uses `||` for OR, so this `if` block will run 3 times: for `poodle`, `Labrador`, and `pug` as long as they are in the `x` array.

Comment: Hey, For some reason When I run the code, it only picks out the first breed, so in this case poodle, it does not click poodle, then Labrador, then the pug /

Comment: I've tried and tried to edit my code, and it's still not selecting the first breed, clicking, then the second breed, then clicking, the third breed and clicking. This is annoying!